# PHP: multi-column search in array

Tags: php, arrays

how can I search an array matching two or more values?

```
Array
(
    [1440972000] => Array
        (
            [mitarbeiterid] => 1
            [von] => 1441006800
            [doppeltermin] => n
            [stundentermin] => n
            [abgesagt] => n
        )
)
```

I would like to search for "mitarbeiterid" and "von". This is just a example, in this array are a few hundred entries.

I only know how to search for e.g. "von" but how to combine the search parameters?

Comment: Maybe you can use some recursive function.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Have a look at [`array_filter()`](http://php.net/array_filter)

```
$filtered_array = array_filter($your_array, function($val){
              return ($val['mitarbeiterid']=='something' and $val['von']=='something');
          });
```

To use outside variables, inside lambda function, use `use` keyword

```
$var1 = 'something';
$var2 = 'something';
//                                                         ▼
$filtered_array = array_filter($your_array, function($val) use($var1, $var2){
    return ($val['mitarbeiterid']==$var1 and $val['von']==$var2);
});
```

Comment: Ok, looks very good, but how do I pass some variables through to the callback function? Something like this $filtered_array = array_filter($your_array, function($val, $employees, $timestamp)...?

Comment: @rwur use Closure - see https://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php

Comment: @viral if you are going to edit the answer, you might as well show the most modern syntax with arrow functions and the removal of `use()`.