# PHP way to filter a big array by key?

Tags: php, arrays, php-7

I get a big data collection from a API, the array what I get has more objects who contains: id, name, place, zip.

Now I need to create filter this array, the code is:

```
$all_objects = $api_result->body->objects;
```

Of course I can do it with a *foreach()*, but what is the best way also for performances to filter it like get object by id 973?

Comment: and what's `$all_objects`?

Comment: edit your question with $all_objects's sample data or link of that api which you are calling. Use array_filter or you can check using array_key_exists functions for faster result.

Comment: ever heard of `array_filter`.

Comment: If you need to do a lot of lookups, you might want to re-index your array using the id as the key.

Comment: @Federkun this are real estate items, that's reason why it is objects :)

Comment: That's not what I, or anybody, asked you to provide.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [array_filter](http://php.net/manual/es/function.array-filter.php).

Assuming `$all_objects` is an array of objects with  public properties as `id`, `name`, etc...

Example code:

```
$lookup = 973
$filtered = array_filter($all_objects, function($object) use($lookup) {
  return ($object->id === $lookup);
});
```

And now `$filtered` only have one (presumably) object with a public property "id" having 973

Note: As both @timurib and @federkun indicate, this is not the FASTEST way to filter an array. Doing a plain foreach would be, all other things being equal, [faster](http://www.levijackson.net/are-array_-functions-faster-than-loops/). But you'd be shaving milliseconds and it could be argued that use of `array_*` functions make the code clearer.

Comment: `array_filter` definetly is _not_ more effective then `foreach`. Function call in the PHP requires some overhead and always slower then inline code execution. If the question about perfomance then `array_filter` is wrong solution.

Comment: This isn't wrong, but the OP asked for the `the best way`, O(1), while `array_filter` has a time complexity of O(N)

Comment: You are both right. Didn't pick up on the **performance** part. Considering the code I assumed a more basic level of competence, which might have been wrong. My bad. I'll update the answer.

Comment: Can the `use` keyword accept an array? Example `use($my_array)`.I have searched for its doc ,so far none

Comment: @ovicko, yes, it can accept any variable. the array wont be expanded, but inherited by the closure as is. you can pass several variables as well.

Comment: @yivi I got it <https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32333436/php-multi-column-search-in-array>  and really got confused.I have an array with 14 keys and was looking for away to filter the array with any any key(s)