# How to check/find specific data from array

Tags: php

I have following array :

```
    [2] => Array
        (
            [main_type] => amount
            [main_value] => amount
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [main_type] => amount
            [main_value] => code
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [main_type] => hello
            [main_value] => amount
        )
```

Now I want to find that if `main_type = hello` and `main_value = amount` is exists or not in entire array. How can i find through entire array.

I have tried using `array_search` but with that i am able to search in one column but not for more than 1.

Comment: You can do it by Foreach:     $found_in_array = false;
    foreach($arr as $dt){
        if($dt["main_type"] == "sendfee" && $dt["main_value"] == "amount"){
            $found_in_array = true;
            break;
        }
    }
    if($found_in_array == true){
        echo "Found";
    }

Comment: I do not want to use foreach.

Comment: Check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32333436/php-multi-column-search-in-array/32333528

Answer (score 0):

You can use array_filter for checking:

See Example Code:

```
$var1 = 'hello';
$var2 = 'amount';                                                           ▼
$filtered_array = array_filter($your_array, function($val) use($var1, $var2){
  return ($val['main_type']==$var1 and $val['main_value']==$var2);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Please use PHP's `array_filter` function with callback.
Here's [array_filter](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php)

```
$var1 = 'hello';
$var2 = 'amount';
$result = array_filter($arr, function ($var) use ($var1, $var2) {
    return ($var['main_type'] == $var1 && $var['main_value'] == $var2);
});
//print_r($result);
```